# Email Tracking Conversion in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Analytics builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein-analytics, analytics, campaign

I am not able to track conversion in Analytics Builder.

I have associated a campaign to an email and also I have used an URL which redirects to the website in the email.

example : `<a href="https://www.google.com" conversion="true" ><b>click here</b></a>`

I have also installed collect code in my website.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be aware, that [Conversion Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_conversion_tracking.htm&type=5) and Web & Mobile Analytics [Collect Code](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_collect_code.htm&type=5) are two different applications with different use cases.

The first one indeed solves your use case, since it keeps track on conversions coming from emails - You can use this data for reporting purposes. It however uses an entirely different tracking script than W&MA. Details about how to configure the tracking can be found in the first link above. Once you have implemented the script, [here is how you can test it](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247399&type=1).

[W&MA collects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_collect_code.htm&type=5) information which is used to populate the W&MA dashboard, and help personalising Einstein Recommendations. The conversions tracked there can be used for recommendation scenarios which take purchase into consideration: e.g. customers who bought X also bought Y. Also details about most purchased products are displayed in W&MA dashboard, based on this data.

If you want to [register purchases using W&MA](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_track_conversion.htm&type=5), please implement this code on your order confirmation page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);       
_etmc.push(["trackConversion", { "cart": [
{"item" : "INSERT_ITEM", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY" , "price" : "INSERT_PRICE","unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" } ,
{"item" : "INSERT_ITEM", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY" , "price" : "INSERT_PRICE" ,"unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" }],
// OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
"order_number" : "INSERT_ORDER_NUMBER",
"discount" : "INSERT_DISCOUNT",
"shipping" : "INSERT_SHIPPING",
"details" : { "AttributeName" : "Value" }
// END OPTIONAL PARAMETERS       
}]);      
</script>
```

I know it can be confusing having two different tracking scripts collecting same information, but the Einstein Recommendation features are based on an acquisition (IGO Digital), made by Exacttarget some years back, and data from here has limited integrations with the rest of the platform. I however hope, my explanation has shed some light on these differences.

Comment: @LukasLunaw Thank You for explaining the difference between the two. Can you also share how can I populate the email conversion tracking graph in W&MA? I do not know which tracking script to use in order to populate the above-mentioned graph

Comment: I have edited my answer with the code for conversion tracking using W&MA

Comment: I have implemented all the collect code to get the most searched items products viewed. But I am not able to understand how would Email conversion graph be populated?

Comment: According to documentation, it will only collect data for identified visitors: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_email_conversion_tracking.htm&type=5

Comment: Do I have to send some emails with the website link to get the data? On the W&MA Dashboard, I can see that the current logged in user as an identified user.

Comment: Yes - as it states in the NOTE in the last link I shared

Comment: Than you it worked

Comment: @LukasLunow appreciate your insights! Can you elaborate on your statement about the limited integrations with the rest of the platform of IGO data? From my experience the IGO and PI data extensions are readily available and are easier accessed than the Conversion Tracking data (via Extract and them Import).

Comment: @ArthurNoort - the single "integration" only pushes the data to data extensions. There is no entry event in JB, you can't use this data in native reporting in SFMC, abandoned cart implementation requires a support ticket, etc. So more gaps than integrations.